# Cantor set is homeomprohic to inverse limit of finite sets

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that the Cantor set (with subspace topology from closed interval $[0,1]$) is homeomorphic to the inverse limit of a system of finite sets.

I considered the following inverse system:

$A_0=\{0,1\}$,

$A_1=\{0,\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1\}$ with map $A_1\rightarrow A_0$ by $0,1/3\mapsto 0$ and $2/3,1\mapsto 1$.

$A_2=\{0,\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}, \frac{3}{9}, \frac{6}{9}, \frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9},1\}$ and map $A_2\rightarrow A_1$ given by: send first two points (of $A_2$) to $0$, next two to $1/3$ etc.

In this way an inverse system of discrete topological spaces is considered.

How can I prove that the inverse limit of this system of topological spaces is **homeomorphic** to the Cantor set (with subspace topology from $[0,1]$)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Probably I would try proving that the universal property is satisfied.

Comment: Have you tried any function from $\prod A_i \to C$?

Comment: @Milten: I read the statement in Weibel's book on Hom.Alg., and tried to give a proof in a pictorial way; I came up to construct inverse system (which is not mentioned in Weibel's book). But then proving homomorphism I couldnt get any click in mind.